# How do I set up server logs?

Tags: apache

I can't find the server access log (I think its because I have free hosting) which shows who have recently visited my website. How can I set it up manually? I have a Apache server.

Comment: Can't find isn't the same thing as not on. Have you actually confirmed your host–who is it?–isn't offering it already? (And if it isn't on, it's unlikely a free host gives you the access to do it yourself.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first instance I would contact your hosting provider and ask them.

If they don't currently have it set up and refuse to set anything up for you then you might have to go for a third party tool.

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is what I would recommend.

Comment: How do I setup a log for a custom directory in Google Analytics?

Comment: This is out of scope of this question, but you would monitor the entire site and filter the results inside Analytics.